# Do not sent ID created by extjs, instead send null

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have added configuration in model like

```
idProperty: 'RULE_ID'
```

It works fine, but during insert it value is like

```
Abc.view.report.report.Model-1
```

When its a new record i want to send like null or ''. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help.  As the docs point out, you'll get non-phantom IDs from the URL (assuming REST).

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.data.writer.Json.html#cfg-writeRecordId